# Disable syntax highlighting in Bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

How do I disable syntax highlighting all together? The built-in highlighting through Pandoc is of no use to me and I'd like to use either highlight.js or a different highlighter for my Gitbook output.

I've tried adding `pandoc_args: --no-highlight` to `_output.yml`. I can see that that option does indeed get passed to Pandoc, but it doesn't do anything. I still get (poor) highlighting.

All I want from my fenced blocks is  tags, nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#appearance-and-style, try setting `highlight: null` in your YAML header?

```
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: null
```

Comment: Aha thanks. That option wasn't listed in https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/yaml-options.html